# Single word for "Without any mistakes"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that denotes the meaning "without any mistakes", or "without any errors?

Comment: You mean ***correct***?

Comment: Aside from the obvious "mistakeless".

Comment: @Josh61: Hm. Now this question sounds stupid. Should I delete it?

Comment: Formal or informal?

Comment: @Josh61: Is there a difference between mistakeless and correct?

Comment: @LittleEva: Formal

Comment: How about "impeccable" or (I've already used this once today) "flawless"?

Comment: "Accurate", "perfect" - have you tried searching for synonyms for words such as these?

Comment: ODO gives _error-free_. And _faultless_ as a synonym. Then one can use a thesaurus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**impeccable**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=impeccable+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: (of behavior, performance, or appearance) in accordance with the highest standards of propriety; faultless. "a man of *impeccable* character"
>
> **synonyms**: flawless, faultless, unblemished, spotless, immaculate, pristine, stainless, perfect, exemplary;
>
> [**flawless**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=flawless&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=flawless+definition&gs_l=hp..1.0l5j41l3.0.0.3.372096...........0.jUVw6bzIN0&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: without any blemishes or imperfections; perfect. "her brown *flawless* skin"
>
> **synonyms**: perfect, unblemished, unmarked, unimpaired; see, Google

Comment: +2.......for summoning flawless again.

Comment: @Mysti Sinha - I'm a "one-trick pony"!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should accept "impeccable" or see if **[immaculate](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/immaculate)** fits in.

> Immaculate means spotless, pure, and clean as fresh snow on a far-off
>   mountain. ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/immaculate))
>
> It also means-
>
> **Free from fault or error**: *an immaculate record on the job*.
>   ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immaculate))

Synonyms: ***faultless***, impeccable, perfect, 
being complete of its kind and without defect or blemish